# I am getting an Invalid provider type specified on call to GetRSAPrivateKey

Tags: c#, encryption, x509certificate2, certificate-store

I have a service that uses a private key for encryption. When I give the service administrative privileges, it works. With normal privileges, it does not. I get the error "Invalid provider type specified" when calling GetRSAPrivateKey().

```
var data = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
var dataList = data.ToList();

using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
using (var aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    byte[] key;
    using (var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, CertificateName, false)[0])
    {
        var publicKey = cert.GetRSAPublicKey();
        var encryptLength = publicKey.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxxxxxx"), RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512).Length;
        var encryptedKey = dataList.Take(encryptLength).ToArray();
        dataList.RemoveRange(0, encryptLength);
        var privateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
        key = privateKey.Decrypt(encryptedKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);
    }
```

If the key does not exist, it is added to the store programmatically during setup.

```
var rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
var request = new CertificateRequest($"cn={CertificateName}", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
var cert = request.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(50));
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\temp\\EncryptionCert.pfx", cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, _certificatePassword));
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
using (var cert = new X509Certificate2("c:\\temp\\EncryptionCert.pfx", _certificatePassword,
                    X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet))
{
    store.Add(cert);
}
```

Is there a non-administrator account setting that allows access to the certificate store, or something that I am doing wrong in my code when loading it?

Answer (score 2):

Only administrators and local system has access to keys in Local Machine store. For client applications that run under different security context, a `CurrentUser\My` store shall be used. And do not use any other store than `My` to store certificates with private key. Otherwise, you can open a vulnerability when keys from Local Machine store are propagated down to all users on a system. Only `My` store is not propagated to other users.

Comment: I did not mention that there is a tray app for configuring the service that the network administrator can use. Since this may not be the same login as the service is running under, I believe the certificate must be in the Local Machine store. Does this mean my only option is to run the service under either Local System or make the account an administrator?

Comment: Why not to use Current User store?

Comment: If the service runs under user A, and administrator B logs in and tries to open the settings with areas that need to be decrypted, then it is my understanding that the tray app would not be able to access the certificate stored in user A's Current User store. Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: Since service is running under user A, then service has full access to Current User store of user A.

Comment: But does administrator B have full access to the Current User store of user A? B is accessing a settings file that need to be decrypted using a different application--not the service. Both the application and service use the same certificate for the encryption key.

Comment: Administrator B has access to user A's cert store as your service exposes. The question lacks information about your context and use case.